# How to open files in search result in client app

Tags: sharepoint-online, search

Sharepoint Online - Modern Search

When searching for a file, clicking on it doesn't open it in the client app.
It also creates some kind of 'unique sharinglink' *(ex: tenant.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/sites/...)*

When browsing to the site and library, the file will open in the client app.

When browsing to the *old* searchpages, I can set the setting to open in client and it works.

When using the new searchbar, on top of every site... it doesn't

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this may be not doable in modern search for us to make the files in search results be opened in client. Configuring the settings to open documents in client applications will not affect modern search.

Similar reference:
[Why can't Office documents be forced to open in client application than online?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/247744/why-cant-office-documents-be-forced-to-open-in-client-application-than-online)